# how to suppress "chapter" in \chapter (while keeping numbering)

Tags: sectioning, chapters, naming

Using `\chapter` I get:

> Chapter 1. The meaning of this novel
>   Chapter 2. The plot of this novel
>   Chapter 3. The moral of this novel

I want to get instead:

> 1. The meaning of this novel
>   2. The plot of this novel
>   3. The moral of this novel

Comment: have you looked at the `titlesec` package?

Comment: Would placing this at the end of your document header help? `\makeatletter\def\chaptername{\@ifnextchar\ \@gobble\relax}\makeatother`

Answer (score 19):

Chapters inside the standard `book` and `report` document classes have their headings constructed via `\@makechapterhead`:

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%                                 % Insert 50pt (vertical) space
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont         % No paragraph indent, ragged right
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne                   % If you should number chapters
      \if@mainmatter                               % ... and you're in \mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter % huge, bold, Chapter + number
        \par\nobreak                               % paragraph break without page break
        \vskip 20\p@                               % Insert 20pt (vertical) space
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M                           % Penalty
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak                 % Huge, bold chapter title
    \vskip 40\p@                                   % Insert 40pt (vertical) space
  }}
```

In order to get rid of some of this titling in the chapter heading (yet keep the ToC untouched), redefine the above `\@makechapterhead` to your liking. For example, the following redefinition removes the reference to "Chapter", and also places the title next to the number. I've included it in the form of a minimal working example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{The meaning of this novel}\lipsum[1-100]
\chapter{The plot of this novel}\lipsum[1-100]
\chapter{The moral of this novel}\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided some dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style.

Comment: This example works well if the document class is "book", but if I change it to "report" I get errors. It still does what it is supposed to do, but how can I get rid of these errors?

Comment: @Spectrosaurus: `report` does not have a distinction between "front matter" and "main matter". As such, `\if@mainmatter` does not exist. You can remove that part as in [this example](https://pastebin.com/raw/fbkmCL2d).

Comment: Thank you, that explains it! I have to say, this is quite complicated for something that a lot of people often want for their thesis. It might be worth considering to turn this into a package with a few simple commands (for example integration into the header, so that the header does not say "Chapter X" anymore either). Just thinking out loud - if I ever get to the point where I'm more comfortable with Latex coding, I might do this myself.

Answer (score 16):

The absolute easiest way to get rid of the word `Chapter` is to use the corresponding book or report-classes from the [KOMA-script-bundle](http://www.tug.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script). The classes `scrbook` and `scrreprt` have your preferred type of headings as standard. The `KOMA-script` class files use sans serif font for headings as standard, and if you prefer Roman font in the headings, you change all headings in one go by adding the command:

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
```

in your preamble.

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument

\appendix
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

That is, you just replace

```
\documentclass{book}
```

with

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
```

and add to your preamble

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
```

**Edit 10 February 2017**

If you prefer to use the standard classes and only want to get rid of the name `chapter`, *i.e*. keeping the chapter number on a separate line, you can just redefine the `\chaptername`-macro:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{} %% remove the word \chapter

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{The meaning of this novel}\lipsum[1-100]
\chapter{The plot of this novel}\lipsum[1-100]
\chapter{The moral of this novel}\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you're using the `book` or `report` document class (or a document class that loads either one of these classes), you could achieve your objective by loading the following code -- which is mostly a quick adaptation of the code for the macro `\@makeschapterhead` (for *unnumbered* or "starred" chapter headings) in `book.cls` -- in your document's preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge\bfseries  \thechapter.\quad #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

Note that the default amounts of vertical whitespace above and below the chapter header are 50pt and 40pt, respectively. Feel free to change these settings to suit your needs.