# renew command chapter - suppress "chapter" show only number and name

Tags: chapters

I am using the report document class and would like to define the following behaviour when using the chapter command:

Normally it makes the chapter the following way:

```
\chapter{Theory}
```

> Chapter 1 Theory

I would like to make it look the following:

> 1 Theory

I know this sounds a lot like just using an article and sections but I want to use sections and subsections in my chapters.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62516/15925 help?

Comment: yes. Perfect by just using scrrprt!