# Remove the word "chapter" in book class and put number in the white margins at the same time

Tags: sectioning, numbering, margins, chapters

I am working on my thesis in the book class, I work in Kile under Linux. So this is an overview of my latex code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% ### Chapter title style ###
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \Huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

% put section numbers in white marigin
\makeatletter 
\def\@seccntformat#1{\llap{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}} 
\makeatother 


\begin{document}

 \chapter{Introduction}

 \section{First section}

 \section{Second section}


\end{document}
```

The code for suppressing the word chapter is from [this topic on stachexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62516/how-to-suppress-chapter-in-chapter-while-keeping-numbering).

This is what the document looks like:

[image]

So to be clear, I would like the number 1. to be in the white margins as well.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\@seccntformat` is responsible for `\section` etc., but not for chapters. Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments

Comment: I am not that familiar with latex code, do you know what I should use for chapters?

Edit: Thanks for the welcome btw! I am working on a compilable document now.

Comment: I edited my question, there is a compilable document now. It doesn't change much, but I assume the question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for (anything) outside is basically the same for `\@seccntformat` as for `\chapter`, however, there's a vertical skip normally and this has to be `unskipped` back to the old position.

Remove the `showframe` package later on -- it's only there to show that the number is now outside of the regular text body.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@\normalfont\raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
    \if@mainmatter%
    \Huge\bfseries\llap{\thechapter.\hfill\space}%
    \vskip-\baselineskip
    \fi%
    \fi%
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \nobreak\Huge\bfseries #1\nobreak%%
    \vskip 40\p@
  }
}

\def\@seccntformat#1{\llap{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}} 
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First longer chapter title}
\section{First section}
\chapter{Second}

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\INSANELYHUGE}{\fontsize{100}{120}\selectfont}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@\normalfont\raggedright \normalfont%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
    \if@mainmatter%
    \INSANELYHUGE\bfseries\llap{\thechapter.\hfill\space}%
    \vskip-\baselineskip
    \fi%
    \fi%
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \nobreak\INSANELYHUGE\bfseries #1\nobreak%%
    \vskip 40\p@
  }
}

\def\@seccntformat#1{\llap{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}} 
\makeatother



\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First longer chapter title}
\section{First section}
\chapter{Second}

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps, one should remove the `.` after the chapter number

Comment: Thank you Christian, this does the job for me! I don't mind the `.`, I actually prefer it that way.

Comment: @Koen: Alright then -- happy TeXing! ;-)

Comment: One more question though; Do you know an easy way to make the font for the chapter title even bigger? I know \Huge is the largest font available, but I would like to make the chapter title appear more prominent.

Comment: @KOEN: `\fontsize{size}{skip}\selectfont` is the command to switch to another size, but this depends on the scalings provided by the font (otherwise, you get warnings).  Using `lmodern` fonts however you can use larger fontsizes. See the `\INSANELYHUGE` command in the update.

Comment: Thank you once again Christian! I was already looking for something like this and now I actually got it working by using the `lmodern` package.

Comment: @Koen: Yes ;-) But please don't update this question again ;-)

Comment: Haha sorry, this was the last time :)