# Applying Chappg Expediently When Only Chapter Numbers in Title are Required

Tags: chapters, page-numbering

The following code makes use of the `chappg` package to define the page numbers as chapter numbers.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[noauto]{chappg}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\arabic{chapter}}    

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\chapter{} 
%\chapter*{1} \setcounter{chapter}{1}
\lipsum[1-4]
\chapter{} 
%\chapter*{2} \setcounter{chapter}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{} 
%\chapter*{3} \setcounter{chapter}{3}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

And it works quite nicely, except that the word "Chapter" appears to the left of the chapter number; e.g.,

[image]

I know that using, say, `\chapter*{1}` will print out only the number 1; `\chapter*{2}` only the number 2; and so forth... but when I replace each `\chapter{}` with `\chapter*{number}`, the pagenumbering is thrown out of whack and displays only zeros.

The following (cumbersome) code corrects this and gives me what I am looking for:

```
\begin{document}
\LARGE
%\chapter{} 
\chapter*{1} \setcounter{chapter}{1}
\lipsum[1-4]
%\chapter{} 
\chapter*{2} \setcounter{chapter}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]
%\chapter{} 
\chapter*{3} \setcounter{chapter}{3}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, to keep specifying `\setcounter{chapter}{#}` will become unwieldy when there are a lot of chapters in the document.

QUESTION: What is an optimal way to have (i) the chapters indicated by their numbers only, and (ii) the page numbers represent those chapter numbers---without resorting to the continual use of `\setcounter{chapter}{#}` each time a new chapter is introduced? Is it possible to avoid also, the continual use of `\chapter*{#}` and replace it with something analogous to `\chapter{}` as in the MWE? (`\chapter*{}` does not work)?

Thank you.

Comment: you are not using the package. And how to format a chapter title is quite unrelated to page numbering.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer `\usepackage[noauto]{chappg}` is used in the MWE; also, the formatting of the chapter title adversely affects the code in the MWE, thus necessitating a much more complicated and laborious approach to accomplishing what the MWE does, with the only change being the formatted title. Thus I ask, how may `\chappg` be used (most) efficiently in this case.

Comment: yes, I know that you load the package. But you are not *using* it. The main purpose of the package is to provide `\pagenumbering{bychapter}`.

Comment: and to get chapter number without prefix the easiest it to switch the class, e.g. scrbook does this by default, and with memoir you get it with `\chapterstyle{section}`.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer The trouble is that the larger document in which the new pagenumbering is to be applied is in book class. Based on what you say about `\pagenumbering{bychapter}`, I will probably reread some of the documentation on `chappg`; and in particular, `[auto]` vs. `[noauto]` for starters. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: then look for one of the various packages which redefine chapter titles https://ctan.org/topic/headings. or redefine `\@makechapterhead` e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299102/2388

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks again. It seems if I can easily eliminate the word "chapter" from each occurrence, there will be no need for `chappg`.